# Using dependency properties when window is created in code

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a dependency property used to specify whether a window may be closed with the Escape key or not. I use it like this:

```
    <Window x:Class="xxxx.xxxx.Client.View.AboutView"
        ...
    xmlns:utilities="clr-namespace:xxxx.xxxx.Client.Utilities"
    utilities:WindowUtilities.CloseOnEscape="True"
        ...
    </Window>
```

But how do I use this dependency property when the window is created in code? Here's an example:

```
    var window = new Window();

    var someView = new SomeView
    {
        DataContext = new SomeView()
    };
    window.Content = someView;
    return window.ShowDialog();
```

The code for the dependency property looks like this:

```
public static class WindowUtilities
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseOnEscapeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CloseOnEscape",
        typeof (bool),
        typeof (WindowUtilities),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, CloseOnEscapeChanged));

    public static bool GetCloseOnEscape(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool) d.GetValue(CloseOnEscapeProperty);
    }

    public static void SetCloseOnEscape(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(CloseOnEscapeProperty, value);
    }

    private static void CloseOnEscapeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = d as Window;
        if (target != null)
        {
            if ((bool) e.NewValue)
                target.PreviewKeyDown += Window_PreviewKeyDown;
            else
                target.PreviewKeyDown -= Window_PreviewKeyDown;
        }
    }

    private static void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = sender as Window;

        if (target != null)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
                target.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
WindowUtilities.GetCloseOnEscape(this);.
```

Similarly you can use `SetCloseOnEscape` also

Comment: WindowUtilities.SetCloseOnEscape(window, true) worked! Thank you, it was simpler than i thought.

Comment: Had to wait one minute before I could. ;)